# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open - Ruby on Rails Win10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error that prevents me from using rails on Windows 10.

I just created the project using ruby 3.1.2p20 with rails 7.0.3.1. For some reason, I can get the rails version but not run **any** other commands. I get a massive unreadable stack of libraries failing one after another. The name of the error and error message say nothing useful, as well as the internet.

What can I do? I am trying to work on this project with a colleague that uses a linux-based system.

[image: Absolutely useless error stack]

Comment: I think there is no enough information to help. Would you add some more like the command you used from the app creation with rails new `_recipe-app_` to the command raising the Errno::ENOENT error? and also do you have any other ruby or rails version installed?

Comment: @Moussa the commands I used were: `rails new recipes-app --database=postgresql`, `bundle install`, and then `rails s`.

Comment: have you tried `bin/rails s` ?

Comment: Yes, it just asks what app do I want to use that command with.